# Why Is Blazor Publishing An Old JSON File?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, visual-studio-2022

I have written a relatively simple app in Blazor WebAssembly. I now want to change the SQL Server database's name from 'blazorTest' (as this started out as proof-of-concept) to 'softwareCensus' (the substantive name for the app). I changed the name on the database server and in the connection string within SoftwareCensus.Server/appsettings.json. This change-over works fine when I run the app out of Visual Studio 2022.

However, when I Publish the app to another server on our network (where it will reside), appsettings.production.json is created within the 'Server' folder. This file has 'blazorTest' in the connection string, and is apparently used by the app because I end up with 500 errors when I run the app off of the server.

If I manually change the connection string in appsettings.production.json on the other server to 'softwareCensus', everything runs correctly then. However, I don't want to have to manually change a file every time I publish an update to the app :P.

I have searched my Solution for the text 'blazorTest', and it doesn't appear anywhere. However, every time I Publish to the server, appsettings.production.json is created or modified within the 'Server' folder to include the 'blazorTest' database name.

I tried to correct this by creating an appsettings.production.json file in the SoftwareCensus.Server Project (beneath appsettings.json). This new file contained 'softwareCensus' in the connection string, but Publishing continues to put out an appsettings.production.json file with the old database name.

Where is this old connection string information coming from for appsettings.production.json, and how do I edit that information to reflect the new database name?

Comment: How do you Publish and what settings for the db are in the publish profile?

Answer (score 1):

Guided by Henk's comment, I found the solution. Within the `Publish...` page for the Server project, there is a `Show All Settings` link. Following that link, there is a `Databases` section. That section had the old connection string in it. Updating the connection string there and re-`Publish`-ing fixed the issue.